# Different sizes of scrollview pages

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I like to set one page from my `UIScrollView` bigger than the others. The last page should be the same size like the whole `UIView`, is that possible?

That's my unfinished code:

```
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    let scrollviewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    let scrollviewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.width

    let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.width

    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let imgTree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth*2, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let feedbackView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth*3, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight))

    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "preview1")
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "preview2")
    imgTree.image = UIImage(named: "preview3")

    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTree)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(feedbackView)

    self.addChildFeedBack(feedbackView: feedbackView)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.width * 4, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

The `feedbackView` is the one, which should be the biggest.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking... Have you *tried* this? If so, did it work? If so, what are you asking? If it did **not** work, what was wrong? If you haven't even ***tried*** it, well... try it and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it like the code above and it did not work. Like that, the feedbackView (which should be the same size like the view) has the size of the full View but in the ScrollView. So it does not fit.

Comment: OK - you are enabling "paging" of the scrollView. That means it will automatically use "pages" the size of itself. If you want the 4th view to be larger, it will need to be "scrollable". One option would be to watch `scrollViewDidScroll`, detect when you've reached the `feedbackView`, and then disable paging. Of course, that would allow the user to "slide back" to the 3rd view... So, how do you *want* the result to function? What do you want the user experience to be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will give you the type of result you want, but something to try...

Instead of adding `feedbackView` to your `scrollView`, add another `UIScrollView` as the 4th subview, and then add `feedbackView` as a subview of *that* scroll view:

```
    // your original setup code
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    let scrollviewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    let scrollviewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.width

    let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height
    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.width

    let imgOne = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let imgTwo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let imgTree = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth*2, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))
    let feedbackView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth*3, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight))

    imgOne.image = UIImage(named: "preview1")
    imgTwo.image = UIImage(named: "preview2")
    imgTree.image = UIImage(named: "preview3")

    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgOne)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTwo)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imgTree)

    // don't add feedbackView to scrollView
    // self.scrollView.addSubview(feedbackView)

    // instead, create another scroll view, 
    //    add feedbackView to that scroll view, 
    //    and add that scroll view as the 4th "page" in scrollView

    let fbScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollviewWidth*3, y: 0, width: scrollviewWidth, height: scrollviewHeight))

    // just so we can see where it is during development
    fbScrollView.backgroundColor = .purple

    // feedbackView will now be in its own scroll view, so
    // set its origin to 0,0
    feedbackView.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero

    fbScrollView.addSubview(feedbackView)
    fbScrollView.contentSize = feedbackView.frame.size

    // add the new scroll view to the "paging" scrollView
    self.scrollView.addSubview(fbScrollView)

    // and the rest of your setup
    self.addChildFeedBack(feedbackView: feedbackView)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.width * 4, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
```